# ng-model is number, select box option values are strings

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have the following code

```
  <select ng-disabled="currentQuestion.id" ng-change="loadTopics()" class="detail-subject-select browser-default" ng-model="currentQuestion.SubjectId">
      <option disabled="disabled" value="any">Choose a Subject</option>
      <option value="1">K8-English</option>
      <option value="2">K8-Math</option>
    </select>
```

The issue is that value 1 and 2 are strings. I need them to be numbers. Everything works fine when I select one on my page, but I need the select box to initialize with the value of (currentQuestion.SubjectId which is a number) when the page loads.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to define your options as an array of objects in your controller like this:

$scope.options = [{
    value: 1,
    name: 'K8-English'
  }, {
    value: 2,
    name: 'K8-Math'
  }];

And implement this in your HTML using ng-options like this:

```
<select ng-disabled="currentQuestion.id"
    ng-change="loadTopics()"
    class="detail-subject-select browser-default"
    ng-model="currentQuestion.SubjectId"
    ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in options">
        <option disabled="disabled" value="any">Choose a Subject</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard HTML attributes (like "value") always mean strings. Unfortunately, You can only achieve this with ng-options:

> Support for select models with non-string values is available via
>   ngOptions.
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

It may seem a bit dirty, but with more options You actually save some typing:

```html
<select
        ng-disabled="currentQuestion.id"
        ng-change="loadTopics()"
        class="detail-subject-select browser-default"
        ng-model="currentQuestion.SubjectId"
        ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in {
                    'K8-English': 1,
                    'K8-Math': 2
                    }"
        >
  <option
          disabled="disabled"
          value=""
          >Choose a Subject</option>
</select>
```